# Cant connect to Sharepoint 2010 web services - unknown document type

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to connect to sharepoint 2010 web services from a mvc project, I go to add service reference(advanced - add web reference) type the

url/_vti_bin/lists.asmx(or address of any other service); I get

*the document at the url was not recognized as a known document type. The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem: document tyoe is not recognized*

If I click on Service Description ; I get

*There was an error downloading url/lists.asmx?wsdl. the request failed with http 404*

I can go to url/_vti_bin/lists.asmx in the browser and  see the list of methods.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting the URL in a browser to verify that it is actually exists.

Comment: ; if I put the url/_vti_bin/lists.asmx to browser; I can get the list of methods